# Is there a way to generate token to access multiple resources under the same tenant for SingleSignOn (SSO) in botframework

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, botframework, azure-ad-msal

So i am developing a chat bot on MS Bot Framework. I want to access multiple resources under my subscription with a single sign on . I am using OAuthPrompt given by MS, but that doesn't allow me to generate token for multiple resources.I have tried multiple delimiters to put multiple resource URLs but it doesn't work . 
I have to signin multiple to get tokens for all the resources. Is it possible to generate a common token to access all the APIs.

I am an amateur  in programming ,so any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/07.advanced-web-chat-apps/e.sso-on-behalf-of-authentication

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Azure Active Directory v1?
There is a function called `getAadTokens` in the BotFrameworkAdapter which can be used to query tokens for multiple resources.

**Javascript example**

```js
const botAdapter = context.adapter;
await botAdapter.getAadTokens(context, this.connectionName, ['https://resource1', 'https://resource2']);
```